# When you fire do bushes become invisible for your allies?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've just watched a very helpful video about camouflage and how bushes work, one thing stated was that "When you fire bushes become invisible within 50m of you."

**So if I'm next to an enemy tank that's behind a shrubbery so my allies can't see it, if I fire at said enemy tank will the shrubberies vanish so that my allies can see my target?**

A crude diagram to illustrate:

```
     M
A    SE
```

A = Ally
M = My Tank
S = Shrubbery
E = Enemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see your enemy and your ally is within radio distance of you and view range of the enemy, they can see the enemy regardless of bush status.

Comment: Doh, completely forgot about that!

Comment: Nevertheless, in rare circumstances the ally can have view radius wider than radio range! In that case this might be useful - they won't receive your radio report but will see the enemy directly!